# Client-only Dropbox access

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I am trying to write an utility that logs into the user's Dropbox account and displays the files there (with some additional formatting, etc) in a browser. I would like to do this with only client-side technologies without any server-side code. Is this possible?

I found this: http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-js/ - haven't tried it yet. It doesn't have much documentation on how to get started. Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

The Chooser API will not allow you to apply custom formatting to files.

If you want to display the user's entire Dropbox, create an application with Full Dropbox access, and use [dropbox.js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js) to read the user's Dropbox.

This walks you through setting up your application: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/master/doc/getting_started.md

This particular snippet (List a Directory's Contents) is most relevant to you: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/master/doc/getting_started.md#list-a-directorys-contents

`readdir` documentation: http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#readdir-instance

The checkbox.js sample application uses `readdir` here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/master/samples/checkbox.js/public/checkbox.coffee#L135

If you run into roadblocks, open an issue on the dropbox.js GitHub page.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser

They have a specialised file for this. Try the demo and start using.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This needs user action. It does not seem possible to get a list of all files and download link for each of them. It will be useful in other contexts though.

Comment: For that you have to use the  REST api and manually get the metadata.

Comment: Yes but it won't be 'client-only'

Comment: Yes it is. You can make api calls from javascript. That way it will be client-only.